# Exchange code for access token and ID token

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-api-client

How to exchange code for access token and id token? I have been following the documentation at
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Post request with:

```
@ : accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?
code=4/QS2fR4UhBantoD-JoJjrT2CSvYaX.EnMe1Y9wBt4cXE-sT2ZLcbKZES74hQI&
client_id=8479957621832pdqb45650bra4oi63s9mchef2m3nvkd.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=RT46Ut_YS9GEejFVDVpl6Orxt&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

returns

> { "error" : "invalid_request" }

What's wrong with the request parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the limited information in the question - but my guess based on the log entry shown is that you are sending a request with all of the parameters inside of the query string (like a GET request, even if you are using the POST method).

Please try again as a POST request, making sure that the form parameters are in the body of the request and a Content-Length is set appropriately - rather than sending them in the query string.

Comment: i am using postman. to send post request. sending data as form data

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what postman is showing before the request is sent?  Alternatively, if you're looking to play around with Google APIs (rather than test OAuth), you might want to look at using API Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/ - it will take care of authentication for you.

Comment: [apology for late reply]. Problem has been solved . I was sending post data as form data instead of form-urlencoded data. thanx anyways

Answer (score 0):

One problem I had was the redirect_uri on the second request (after the sign-in page, when Google sends a code to your "return" uri, and you're trying to exchange it for a token)

That redirect_uri has to be the same as the first one. In other words, it's the uri of the page *you're already on* when you're exchanging the code for the token.

Maybe this isn't a common issue, but it seemed totally logical to me that if the spec was asking for a redirect_uri, it couldn't possibly want the same uri that I already gave them and they just hit a millisecond ago.